# How to get started with Microsofts RibbonControlsLibrary?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, ribboncontrolslibrary

I'm new to WPF programming and decided to give it a shot by trying out some ribbon control libraries.
The library that looks best for now is the Microsoft RibbonControlsLibrary. You can get it on the ribbon licensing page.

So far I've started a new project, added the control to the windows, but them I'm stuck: This is the code so far:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="808" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
    <Grid>
        <my1:Ribbon HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ribbon1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="165" Width="786" ShowQuickAccessToolbarOnTop="False" WindowIconVisibility="Visible" DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="0,-20,0,0">
            <my1:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <my1:RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Hidden" IsEnabled="True" />
            </my1:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <my1:RibbonTab Label="Tab1" Name="rtab1" >
            </my1:RibbonTab>
            <my1:RibbonTab Label="tab2" Name="rtab2"/>
        </my1:Ribbon>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Questions**:
1) Where can I find samples for this ribbon control? I've tried googling, but came up with nothing useful.
2) How to add items to specific ribbon tabs? I'm lost in all these properties in the property grid. So far I havent found a designer for that purpose.
3) How can I switch the designer to show me what icons/button/... I placed on TabPage2?

(FYI: The fluent ribbon library does not seem to work for me, because I can't get rid of the ApplicationMenu.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a great sample/tutorial:

http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/hands-on-labs/entry76491.aspx

The sample provides a manual with explanations and some test projects with step by step instructions to implement the ribbon control.

Though I'm totally new to WPF, I managed to extract necessary classes from the sample to provide a ribon based menu in my program.

Comment: Link now seems to be broken.

Comment: Sorry, I'm also not able to fix the link :-(

Comment: Found this link from the wayback machine that may be useful: https://web.archive.org/web/20120126021248/http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/hands-on-labs/entry76491.aspx